# Form field not working in vuefity v-select

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

After fetching tags from the backend and trying to show them for selection in the form, their name does not appear, the form correctly returns the necessary data, but what is selected is not visible. Another problem is that after selecting and exiting the dropdown, you cannot open the tag selection window again[image: Empty selection menu and no name displayed]

```
          <v-select
          bg-color="rgba(18, 92, 171, 0.14)"
          id="tags"
          v-model="selectedTags"
          label="Tagi"
          :items="tags"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="id"
          chips
          multiple
          ></v-select>
```

The fetched object looks like this

```
0: {id: 1, name: 'Apples'}
1: {id: 2, name: 'Proba 2'}
2: {id: 4, name: 'tag'}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "after selecting and exiting the dropdown, you cannot open the tag selection "?

Comment: When i open v-select with tags and close it after i choose something or not v-select i blocked like I cannot change what i choose and see options again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a non-existing property `item-text`, it should be [`item-title`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-item-title)

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    
    return {
      selectedTags: ref([]),
      tags: [{id: 1, name: 'Apples'},{id: 2, name: 'Proba 2'}, {id: 4, name: 'tag'}
    ]}
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-select
          v-model="selectedTags"
          label="Tagi"
          :items="tags"
          item-title="name"
          item-value="id"
          chips
          multiple
        ></v-select>
        <div>
        seld: {{ selectedTags }}
        </div>
        
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: After this change all problems disappeared